# Get book cover link from online bookstore using IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the image link for the book cover from this page:
https://www.wook.pt/livro/diario-1927-1941-virginia-woolf/21571877

I've inspected the cover:

```
<div class="cover" id="productPageLeftSectionTop-image" data-prodid="21571877"> 

    <img sizes="(max-width: 688px) 75vw, 25vw" srcset="https://img.wook.pt/images/diario-1927-1941-virginia-woolf/MXwyMTU3MTg3N3wxNzQyMTI1NnwxNTQ0NzQ1NjAwMDAw/260x 265w,https://img.wook.pt/images/diario-1927-1941-virginia-woolf/MXwyMTU3MTg3N3wxNzQyMTI1NnwxNTQ0NzQ1NjAwMDAw/320x 325w,https://img.wook.pt/images/diario-1927-1941-virginia-woolf/MXwyMTU3MTg3N3wxNzQyMTI1NnwxNTQ0NzQ1NjAwMDAw/350x 355w,https://img.wook.pt/images/diario-1927-1941-virginia-woolf/MXwyMTU3MTg3N3wxNzQyMTI1NnwxNTQ0NzQ1NjAwMDAw/502x 500w"src="https://img.wook.pt/images/diario-1927-1941-virginia-woolf/MXwyMTU3MTg3N3wxNzQyMTI1NnwxNTQ0NzQ1NjAwMDAw/250x" alt="Wook.pt - Diário 1927-1941" title="Wook.pt - Diário 1927-1941" onclick="" class="img-responsive ">
    </div>
```

I've tried:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.wook.pt/livro/diario-1927-1941-virginia-woolf/21571877", "//div[@class='cover']/@src")
```

but the content comes out empty... I have no idea how to extract the image's link:
https://img.wook.pt/images/diario-1927-1941-virginia-woolf/MXwyMTU3MTg3N3wxNzQyMTI1NnwxNTQ0NzQ1NjAwMDAw/250x

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to retrieve the URL of `https://img.wook.pt/images/diario-1927-1941-virginia-woolf/MXwyMTU3MTg3N3wxNzQyMTI1NnwxNTQ0NzQ1NjAwMDAw/250x` from `https://www.wook.pt/livro/diario-1927-1941-virginia-woolf/21571877`.
- You want to achieve this using the built-in functions of Google Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modified xpath? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='cover']/img/@src")
```

- The xpath was modified from `//div[@class='cover']/@src` to `//div[@class='cover']/img/@src`.
- In this case, the URL of `https://www.wook.pt/livro/diario-1927-1941-virginia-woolf/21571877` is put in the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.